# TCP Traceroute only displaying gateway and final destination

Tags: tcp, network-programming, network-protocols, traceroute

[image]

I am able to successfully trace the route from my PC to neverssl.com via traceroute's ICMP function:

```
traceroute -I neverssl.com
```

which takes about 20 hops (I have not included the output due to the personal IP addresses displayed etc).

However, when using traceroute's TCP function:

```
traceroute -T neverssl.com
```

I get the result in the attached picture. This happens with any website I try.

Is there any reason why I am seeing only the gateway and destination? I have replicated the same results with the "tcptraceroute" package. I am on Ubuntu if it helps.

Comment: What kind of network are you on? Is it possible that you have some sort of transparent proxy in the network?

Comment: Yes, I have also begun to suspect that this is the culprit. I am unfortunately unable to verify whether I do or do not have a transparent proxy on the network but I'm quite certain it's the reason. Is there any way I can close this question and/or should I?

Comment: You can delete it if you want. However, you might (also) want to try asking here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/